# Passing variable names with condition inside FOR loop in R

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R programming. I have a requirement in mind and trying to work it out with for loop. I have a data frame with 14 variables which has empty values for some rows and columns. My requirement is to list the number of empty values in each variable (column).
My code below to achieve it:

```
for (x in names(df)){
  cat(paste("No of rows with empty value for", x, " variable:", 
nrow(df[df$x == '', ])))
}
nrow(df[df$x=='',])
```

From the above `nrow` command, the x value is not getting substituted for `df$x == ''`.

Need some expert help to fix it.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Vin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sapply though to make your code cleaner.

`sapply(df, FUN=function(x) sum(x == ''))`

Answer (score 1):

I slightly altered your for loop, and added a line break in the end. It is easier if you sum over the booleans created than counting the rows.

```
##Create some fake data

df <- data.frame(
    first_var = c(rep("",10),1:10),
    second_var = c(rep("",9), 1:11),
    third_var = c(rep("", 8), 1:12),
    fourth_Var = c(rep("", 7), 1:13)
)

for(i in names(df)){
  cat(paste0("No of rows with empty value for ",i, " variable:",sum(df[,i] == ""),"\n"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. This helped but as Qianbo wang suggested I will go with sapply option.